# I want to display the id of the posted content, it is currently expressed using a variable, so I want to display it using the array index

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner of javascript. Now, I create a application of list.
The content you want to display id "id + element". 
I want to display it using the array index but using variable now.

expected

1:first value
2:second value
3:third value
...

This is code.

html

```
<body>
  <h1>todo list</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button type="button" id='click-function'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="todoList"></ul>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

js

```
const myfunc = document.getElementById('click-function');
let i = 0;
myfunc.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let todoItems = [];
    let todoItem = document.getElementById('item').value;
    todoItems.push(todoItem);
    todoItems.forEach((element,index,array) => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = i + element;
        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(li);
        i++;
    }) 
})
```

Comment: where is this -- `form second` and `form first` coming from?

Comment: Multiple values to enter in one form ,so this is form "<input type="text" id="item">" Sorry,I didn't have enough words

Comment: Please update your question with proper explanation and code. What will be the input and what is expected output. As it seems to be working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your code snippet see the working demo below:

```js
const myfunc = document.getElementById('click-function');
let i = 0;
myfunc.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let todoItems = [];
    let todoInput = document.getElementById('item');
    let todoItem= todoInput.value;
    todoInput.value='';
    todoItems.push(todoItem);
    todoItems.forEach((element,index,array) => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = (i+1)+' ' + element;
        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(li);
        i++;
    }); 
})
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>todo list</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button type="button" id='click-function'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="todoList"></ul>
</body>
```

Explanation:

Js Array has a starting index of 0 so you need to increment the current index by 1 each time you want to display it to the user.

Suggestion:

Instead of printing the index via code, I would suggest you to `<ol>` (ordered list) in place of `<ul>` (unordered list), which will do the work for you.

```js
const myfunc = document.getElementById('click-function');
let i = 0;
myfunc.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let todoItems = [];
    let todoInput = document.getElementById('item');
    let todoItem= todoInput.value;
    todoInput.value='';
    todoItems.push(todoItem);
    todoItems.forEach((element,index,array) => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = element;
        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(li);
        i++;
    }); 
})
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>todo list</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button type="button" id='click-function'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <ol id="todoList"></ol>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have get rid of forEach inside which is redundant.

```js
const myfunc = document.getElementById('click-function');
let count = 0;
let todoItems = [];
myfunc.addEventListener('click',function(){  
    let todoItem = document.getElementById('item').value;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = count++ +' : '+ todoItem;
        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
  <h1>todo list</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button type="button" id='click-function'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="todoList"></ul>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```